# Angular navigate to paypal url response

Tags: node.js, angular, paypal

I am trying to integrate **Paypal API**.
I use `Angular`, `Node.js`, `MongoDB` stack.

I created my payment with success

```
paypal_api.payment.create(create_payment_json, config_opts, function(err,res) {
    var response = {};
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    if (res) {
        if (res.payer.payment_method === "paypal") {
            console.log("Create Payment Response");
            console.log(res);
            response.payment = res;
            response.paymentId = res.id;

            for (var i = 0; i < res.links.length; i++) {
                var link = res.links[i];
                if (link.method === "REDIRECT") {
                    var redirectUrl = link.href;
                }
            }
            response.redirectUrl = redirectUrl;
            resultat.status(200).json({
                message: "Success",
                obj: response
            });
        }
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I retrieve the `redirectUrl` in my FrontEnd, see below

```
PayNow() {
    this.contactClientService.PayNowPaypal().subscribe(
    (paypalObject: Payment) => {
        this.paypalObject = paypalObject;
        console.log(this.paypalObject.redirectUrl);
        this.router.navigate([this.paypalObject.redirectUrl]);
    },
    error => { 
        this.errorMessage = <any>error
    });
}
```

On `this.router.navigate([this.paypalObject.redirectUrl]);`
I understand the error message `"Error: Cannot match any routes."`. I read that I could use `window.location.href = '...';` to go to an external link. But would it be the best method to do that? I am not sure. Any advice ?

If I copy past the link into my browser, I will be redirect to paypal to make my payment.

```
redirectUrl:"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_e....."
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.router.navigate is an angular method that looks for matching routes in your route definitions. Since paypal is giving you an external link it doesn't match any of your application's routes. That is why you are seeing the error *"Error: Cannot match any routes."*

You are correct, when navigating to an external link outside of your app, you should use

```
window.location.href = this.paypalObject.redirectUrl;
```